# Shell script, get/extract mac address from console output of command after "MAC: "

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, scripting, regular-expression

I'm trying to automatically pull out the mac address of a arduino device using a shell script, and need some help how to do this.

This is the output returned by the command:

```
Opening /dev/cu.SLAB_USBtoUART @ 115200...
Connecting to ESP32 ROM, attempt 1 of 10...
Connecting to ESP32 ROM, attempt 2 of 10...
  Connected, chip: ESP32D0WDQ5 R1
efuse_wr_disable     : 0x0084
efuse_rd_disable     : 0x1
flash_crypt_cnt      : 0x01 (WD)
WIFI_MAC_Address     : 0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaa (MAC: aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff)
SPI_pad_config_hd    : 0x0
chip_package         : 0x1
cpu_freq_low         : 0x0
```

I am able to capture this into a shell script variable, but having a hard time trying to extract just the mac address of `aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff`

The output will always be the exact same, `(MAC:` followed by the 17 characters that make up the mac address, then a closing `)`

Can someone please help me with a command I can use on a variable all this output is stored in, to get just the `aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff` portion?  I've been searching and trying for hours without luck, thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `awk`

```
my_command_with_output | awk -F'[()]' '/^WIFI_MAC_Address/{sub(/^.*: /,"");print $1}'
```

You can put it in a varialbe

```
variable=$(my_command_with_output | awk -F'[()]' '/^WIFI_MAC_Address/{sub(/^.*: /,"");print $1}')
```

Print out the content of the variable.

```
echo "$variable"
```

Output

```
aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff
```

Comment: awesome, this works great thank you!!

Comment: Great, good luck with your script. :-)

Comment: would you be able to help with the awk cmd to get the `flash_crypt_cnt` value as well?  Will always be the same format, and value will either be `0x0` or `0x1`  thanks!

Comment: `awk -F'[(:) ]+' '/^flash_crypt_cnt/{print $2}'`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly:

```
echo "$var" |  grep -o "..:..:..:..:.."
```

Output:

```
aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff
```

Comment: Oh wow this was so simple how did i not come across this during my search, works great thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can capture any valid MAC (with a leading space) with this regex:

```
command  |   grep -oE '([ :][[:xdigit:]]{2}){6}'
```

Or, in bash shell:

```
$ regex='(([[:xdigit:]]{2}:){5}([[:xdigit:]]{2}))';
$ [[ $var =~ $regex ]] &&  printf '%s\n' "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff
```